# How do I prevent users to use thousands separator in FileMaker Pro?

Tags: filemaker

In FileMaker Pro, when using number field, the user can choose to use a thousand separator or not. For example, if I have a database with a field for the price of an item, the user can either enter `1,000` or `1000`.

I am using my database to generate an XML file that needs to be uploaded. The thing is, that my XML scheme dictates that only a value of `1000` is allowed and not `1,000`. Therefore, I want to either automatically remove the comma, or (my preference in this case) alert the user when trying to enter a value with a thousand separator.

What I tried is the following.

For the field, I am setting Validation options. For example:

- Require Strict data type: Numeric Only
- Validated by calculation: `Position ( Self ; ","; 1 ; 1 ) = 0`
- Validated by calculation: `Self = Substitue ( Self, ",", "")`
- Auto-enter calculation: Filter( Self ; "0123456789." )

Unfortunately, none of these work. As the field is defined as a number (and I want to keep it like this, as I am also performing calculations based on this number), the `Position` function and the `Substitute` function apparently ignore the thousand separator!

**EDIT:**
Note that I am generating my XML by concatenating a string, for example:

```
"<Products><Product><Name>" & Name & "</Name><Price>" & Price & "</Price></Product></Product>"
```

The reason is that what I am exporting is dependent on the values in my database. Therefore, I am not using the [File][Export records...] function.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: Ooops, sorry

Comment: Just for completeness: validating by calculation = `Position ( Self ; ","; 1 ; 1 ) = 0` or `Self = Substitute ( Self, ",", "")` does work. Validating as Numeric Only does not, because FileMaker recognizes the comma as a valid character for number entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto-enter calculation will work, but you need to uncheck the box "Do not replace existing value of field" (which is checked by default).

I'd suggest using the calculation `GetAsNumber(self)` as the auto-enter calc. If it should only contain integers, wrap that in a call to `Int()`

Answer (score 1):

> I am using my database to generate an XML file that needs to be uploaded. The thing is, that my XML scheme dictates that only a value of 1000 is allowed and not 1,000.

If this is only a problem when you export, why not handle it when exporting?

- If you are exporting as XML using XSLT, you can add an instruction to
  your stylesheet to remove the comma from all number fields;
- Alternatively, you can export from a layout where the field is
  formatted to display without the comma and select the `Apply current's layout data formatting to exported data` option when
  exporting.

---

### Added:

> Perhaps I should have clarified. I am not using the export function to generate the XML as there is some logic involved in how the XML should be formatted (dependent on the data that I want to export). What I do instead is that I make a string where I combine XML-tags and actual values from the database.

IMHO, you're making a mistake by not taking advantage of the built-in XML/XSLT export option. Any imaginable logic can be implemented this way, without burdening your solution with the fragile task of creating a valid XML.

In any case, if you're using the field in a calculation, you can replace all references to it with:

```
GetAsNumber (YourField )
```

to get an unformatted, numeric-only, value.

Comment: Perhaps I should have clarified. I am not using the export function to generate the XML as there is some logic involved in how the XML should be formatted (dependent on the data that I want to export). What I do instead is that I make a string where I combine XML-tags and actual values from the database.

Comment: See the addition to my post.

Answer (score 0):

Your question puzzles me. As far as I know, FileMaker does not store the thousands separator, but rather offers it only as a display option.
That's also why those functions can't find it.
Are you sure you are exporting the raw data and not a "formatted as layout" variant?

Comment: It confuses me as well. You mention that FileMaker does not store the thousands separator. Why is it then, that when I click on the field to re-enter information, it is displayed? Also, I not using any formatting when generating the XML-string.

Comment: FileMaker stores the data 'as entered' - and unless you do something, that's how it exported, too.

Comment: Indeed,@michael.hor257k! Funny thing is, though, that when I do calculations with it, the separator is ignored (even when I did enter it).

Comment: You can apply an auto enter calc to the field that removes the thousands separator and anything unwanted, such as Filter(Self;"0123456789.")

Comment: `GetAsNumber()` would be a better choice, IMHO - but why solve a "problem" where it doesn't exist?

Comment: @AndreasT: I just tried this, but it is not working. It is ignoring the fact that it contains a separator... (I updated my post to include this option)

Comment: Be aware that auto enter options only evaluate when the field is empty or changed. You can do a replace to update all records if you want. I concur with the use of the getasnumber function instead as it is properly localized.